# How to make all textboxes with specific tag accepts only numeric values in ACCESS Form using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with multiple textboxes, I'm looking for a way to make the textbox accept only numeric values if it had a specific tag.

I've found the following code which will do what I want individually.

```
Select Case KeyAscii
    Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, _
    vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
        If KeyAscii = 46 Then If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") Then KeyAscii = 0
    Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
        Beep
End Select
```

Comment: Are textboxes bound to number fields? Why do you need this? Why not use ValidationRule and ValidationText properties? Or BeforeUpdate event to validate data? What exactly is issue? If you want to only enforce this if Tag property has particular content, then use an If Then Else. Exactly what event is this code in?

Comment: Are textboxes bound to number fields? Yes

Comment: I should look into this "ValidationRule and ValidationText properties"

Comment: _which will do what I want individually_ .. so what is your question, please?

Comment: If they are bound to number fields then only number values can be entered. Access will notify user if they try to enter non-numeric value.

Comment: @Gustav 
' I managed to get the names of the controls that im targeting but i wasn't abel to prevent not numeric values

Dim Ctrl As Control

For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
    If Ctrl.Tag = "isNum" Then
        Debug.Print Ctrl.Name
    End If
Next

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a function, then call this from the keypress event of the control if it carries the tag.

Alternatively, if many controls/textboxes, use *WithEvents*.

An example (for the click event) can be found in my project [VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme).

At may take a little to get hold on, but it is very powerful technique and will cut redundant code to a minimum.